# CSS GRIDimage css image with a ghostly grid

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I would like the bottom picture to be at the right wall, maybe I have a mistake in the code I can't see... 
if you see any consideration, please answer maybe we can solve it together

[page preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Eej.jpg)
HTML

```
<HTML>

 <main class="baner">
            <img  class="slider" src="room.png" alt="banner-1">
            <div class="slider-text">
                <h3>Od projektu po realizację</h3>
                    <p>Personalizujemy zarówno proponowane rozwiązania projektowe jak i sam zakres naszej usługi projektowej oraz<br> opieki realizacyjnej dopasowując go
                         do indywidualnych potrzeb inwestorów.</p>
            </div>
            <img  class="slider-2" src="room3.png" alt="banner-1">
            <div class="slider-text-2">
                    <h3>Sprawdzeni wykonawcy</h3>
                        <p>Stworzyliśmy zespół składający się ze sprawdzonych firm wykonawczych oraz dostawców dający możliwość realizacji prac dla najbardziej wymagających
                             klientów.</p>
        </main>
```

CSS

I will add that I am just starting with css grid and maybe you can see some errors, please show them to me and how to solve them

```
.baner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 500px 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 400px 400px ;
    font-family: 'BenchNine', sans-serif;
}

.slider {
    animation: 1.3s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.slider-text {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1fr;
    animation: 1.3s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 2;
}

.slider-text h3 {
    font-size: 2.7em;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.slider-text p {
    font-size: 1.7em;
}


        /* Kolejna czesc strony  */

.slider-2 {



}

.slider-text-2 {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1fr;
    animation: 1.3s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.slider-text-2 h3 {
    font-size: 2.7em;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.slider-text-2 p {
    font-size: 1.7em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these styles:

The `align-self: end` is going to align it to the end, but since the image is not wrapped in a `div`, you are going to have to use `margin-auto` to align it right.

```
.slider-2 {
    align-self: end;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 2;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```